# How can I delete the word js in all p (LowerCase and Uppercase )? in Javascript

Tags: javascript

How can I delete the word js in all p?

```
<p>test test test test test JS</p>
<p>test test test js test</p>
<p>test test Js</p>
<p>test test test test</p>
```

My code:

```
let deleteJs = document.querySelectorAll('p');

deleteJs.forEach(function (item) {    
    if (item.textContent.includes('js')) {
        console.log(item.textContent);
        item.remove();
    }
})
```

Answer (score 2):

This is a perfect use for [regex](https://codeburst.io/javascript-learn-regular-expressions-for-beginners-bb6107015d91)

(...or checkout more details on the topic on the StackOverflow regex [tag](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/regex/info) itself)

```js
var elem =  document.querySelectorAll('p');    
elem.forEach((item) => {
   // g modifier = global
   // i modifier = case-insensitive
   const searchRegExp = /js/gi;
   const replaceWith = '';
 
   const result = item.innerHTML.replace(searchRegExp, replaceWith);
   item.innerHTML = result
});
```

```html
<p>test test test test test JS</p>
<p>test test test js test</p>
<p>test test Js</p>
<p>test test test test</p>
```

Answer (score 1):

You could split and filter the string then join the result back. Something like below:

```js
const msgEl = document.querySelector('#span_msg');
document.querySelector('#btn_delete').addEventListener('click', e => {
  msgEl.innerHTML = msgEl.innerHTML.split(' ').filter(word => word.toLowerCase() != "js").join(' ');
});
```

```html
<span id="span_msg">test test test test test JS test test test js test test test Js test test test test<span>

<button id="btn_delete">Delete</button>
```

Comment: Will fail for case like `"moment.js"`

Answer (score 0):

You need to replace the text with an empty string

```
let deleteJs = document.querySelectorAll('p');

deleteJs.forEach(function (item) {

    if (item.textContent.includes('js')) {
        item.textContent.replace("js", "");
    }
}
)
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using `/(\bjs\s*\b|\b\s*js\b)/gi` as it is much more versatile than the other solutions provided here -

[image: regex101.com]

The regex breaks down like this -

```
/                      /gi  # regex with gi modifiers
 (                    )     # capture group 1
  \b                        # word boundary
    js\s*                   # "js" followed by zero or more whitespace 
          \b                # word boundary
            |               # logical OR
             \b             # word boundary
               \s*js        # zero or more whitespace followed by "js"
                    \b      # word boundary
```

The regex modifiers `/gi` are `g`lobal and case-`i`nsensitive

---

Notice how `\b...\b` wraps both alternatives? We can specify these boundaries just once, if we wanted to -

```
/(\b(?:js\s*|\s*js)\b)/gi
```

This regex breaks down pretty much exactly the same way -

```
/                     /gi  # regex with gi modifiers
 (                   )     # capture group 1
   \b              \b      # begin/end with word boundaries
    (?:           )        # non-capture group
       js\s*               # "js" followed by zero or more whitespace
            |              # logical OR
             \s*js         # zero or more whitespace followed by "js"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  let deleteJs = document.querySelectorAll('p');
deleteJs.forEach(elem=>{
    let Tab=[];
    content=elem.textContent.split(" ");
    content.forEach(e=>{
    let x=e.toLowerCase();
    if(x!=="js"){
    Tab.push(x);
    y=Tab.join(" ");
    
    }

    }) 
    
    elem.innerText=y;
})
```